# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I receive this exception when I try to run a jar file

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
```

The file `servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar` lives in the same dir as the jar im trying to run.

`servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar` contains the class `javax.servlet.Servlet`

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Show the command you are using to run the .jar file.

Comment: Are the imports correct and is it properly referenced in the classpath?

Comment: @Jules: this problem has nothing to do with imports. They can only produce compile-time error. It's more likely to be a classpath issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include its path in the `Class-Path` entry of the `MANIFEST.MF` file of the JAR you're running. Assuming that both JAR's are in the same folder:

```
Class-Path: servlet-api-2.5.6.1.14.jar
```

I only wonder how it's useful to have the Servlet API as a dependeny of a plain Java application.

Answer (score 0):

you would need the servlet apis and any dependent libraries in a web application. 
To run a web applicaton, you will "deploy" it on a servlet container or application server like tomcat, jboss, jetty so on. All the libs to run your web app., which you would need in this way are included in your container/container classpaths. You don't have to define them explicitly in your application configs.

If you are working on *exclusively* an application like an application server, and want to develop a server on yourself, you need to add the servlet library into your app.'s classpath.